# When using a specific Bibtex package to cite, how can I cite without brackets (e.g. adjust the output)?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, cell

I am using one of the Bibtex style packages, the 'cell' package, to handle my referencing (we specifically need to cite in the way the journal Cell does it). It works quite well, but when I cite I always get an output like 'xxxx (Smith et al., 2017)' including the brackets. But I also want to be able to write 'Smith et al, (2017) said xxxx'. Is this possible, and if so, how? I've produced my preamble, an example of citing, and the bibliography thing at the end.

Sorry if this question is poorly asked - I'm very much a beginner!

Many thanks :))

```
%PREAMBLE
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\usepackage{cell}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing %to change line spacing, DO NOT change
\setlength{\parskip}{1em} %to change paragraph spacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}%to change paragraph indent
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\graphicspath{C:/Users/esmee/Dropbox/Cambridge/MVST II/Research Project/Project report/Project graphics}
\usepackage[left=2.8cm, right=2.8cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, headheight=17pt,
includehead, includefoot, heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\footskip}{80pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\usepackage{nonumonpart}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\begin{document}

%Example of citing:

XXXX \cite{wilson_spontaneous_1981}

%End bibliography stuff
\bibliography{References2}
\bibliographystyle{cell}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can see `\usepackage{cell}` only supports one kind of citation output, namely "(Author, Year)". If you want to be able to also use "Author (Year)", you could try `\usepackage{natbib}` instead of `\usepackage{cell}`. **If** you are lucky, `cell.bst` also works well enough with `natbib` so that you can use its `\citet` and `\citep` commands.

Comment: This worked!!! Thank you so much :))))))))